# Does the object key when adding activities need to be unique?

Tags: getstream-io

Should I specify the object id in the 'object' key when adding activities. 
How is this key used by stream exactly, is uniqueness required in this field? For me it's not so important since with the foreign_id I can get back all the information from the actor verb, object, target etc.. during the enrichment process.

If I only specify "$objectType" instead of "$objectType:$objectId" could this cause problems?

```
$data = [
    'actor' => '1',
    'verb' => "$verb",
    // This
    'object' => "$objectType",
    // Or This
    'object' => "$objectType:$objectId",
    'target' => "$targetObjectType:$targetObjectId",
    'time' => "$time",
    'foreign_id' => "$foreignId",
     // Custom field
    'object_type' => $objectType
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object doesn't have to be unique. Foreign id should be unique though. (as it's used for determining uniqueness and we allow you to delete activities by foreign id)

I would recommend using objectType:objectId as this will make it easier for you to enrich the data (query any missing information from your DB) if that's necessary.

Comment: Thanks! So actually one more question, technically from my foreign id I can actually retrieve all the data again, verb, actor, target, object type etc ... so technically isn't that all stream would need, are the other fields suggestions or requirements? Let's imagine I wasn't doing aggregation, could I just push "foreign_id" and "time" and things would still work?